# Performing `mup deploy` a second time crashes Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm, meteorite

The first execution of `mup depoly` works fine. However doing `mup deploy` a second time or running `mup reconfig` will cause Meteor.js to crash.

```
Bundling Started: /var/www/test-app

Started TaskList: Deploying App
[localhost] uploading bundle
[localhost] uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[localhost] setting up env vars
[localhost] setting up env vars: SUCCESS
[localhost] uploading settings.json
[localhost] uploading settings.json: SUCCESS
[localhost] calling deploy script
[localhost] calling deploy script: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
    npm WARN package.json http-proxy@1.0.0 No repository field.
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
    reverted back to the previous version due to the latest version didn't pick up!
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

    > fibers@1.0.1 install /opt/meteor/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
    > node ./build.js

    `linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
    Binary is fine; exiting
    fibers@1.0.1 node_modules/fibers
    meteor stop/waiting
    meteor start/running, process 4087
    meteor stop/waiting
    meteor start/running, process 4112
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Completed TaskList: Deploying App
```

Meteor isn't running after the command has finished running. Would like to know if anyone have solved this problem. Thanks!

Comment: From the `STDERR` it might be that your server has a bit of internet trouble. It couldn't download something, try again and see if it fixes itself

Comment: @Akshat I tried `curl https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers -k` and was able to download fibers. However `mup deploy` still gave the same error

Comment: Its not likely thats the url its fetching. Its some part of fibers. If you look inside that file you're curling it contains more files

Comment: @Akshat is it possible to manually install the file which is not downloading? I wonder which file is not being downloaded

Comment: Here's the actual reason: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/2#issuecomment-30596996

Comment: Check using version `0.1.7` and configure [`deployCheckWaitTime`](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#deploy-wait-time) into a some higher value

Comment: @AthenaWisdom Can you post your solution as an answer and accept it so that we can keep the unanswered questions list clean?